# My jQuery Carousel is not working when using User Controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, carousel

I am creating a web page using ASP.net . I am using an empty web page where I use User Controls instead of a Master Page. I have created 3 User Controls named, `Head.ascx`, `Panel_Left.ascx` and `Panel_Right.ascx`, and call them on a separate empty web form called `Home.aspx`. I need to add a carousel that I made using jQuery to my Home Page. When I add it, it does not work. When I don't embed the `Panel_Right.ascx` User Control to the Home Page, the carousel works perfectly.

Here's my code :

Head.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Head.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.UserCtrls.Head" %>

<link href="../Styles/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="heading">
    <h1 id="sysHead">My First Page</h1>
    <hr />
</div>
```

Panel_Left.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Panel_Left.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.UserCtrls.Panel_Left" %>

<link href="../Styles/Left_Panel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="navigation">
    <asp:Panel ID="nav" runat="server">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>

<div id="pnlBG"></div>
```

Panel_Right.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Panel_Right.ascx.cs" Inherits="Test.UserCtrls.Panel_Right" %>

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/Right_Panel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../Styles/Right_Panel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="arrow">
    <img id="pnlArrow" src="../Images/panel_arrow.png" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="rightPanel">
    <div class="pnlRight">
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlRight" runat="server">
            <div class="annoucePnl">
                <h4 id="announce">Special Announcements</h4>
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="tickBalPnl">
                <h4 id="ticketBal">My Ticket Balance</h4>
            </div>
            <br />

            <div class="blogPnl">
                <h4 id="blog">UL Travel Blog</h4>
            </div>
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Slider() {
            $(".slider #slide_1").show("fade", 500);
            $(".slider #slide_1").delay(5500).hide("fade", 500);

            var sc = $(".slider img").size();
            var count = 2;

            setInterval(function () {
                $(".slider #slide_" + count).show("fade", 500);
                $(".slider #slide_" + count).delay(5500).hide("fade", 500);

                if (count == sc) {
                    count = 1;
                }

                else {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }, 6500);
    }
    </script>

    <link href="Styles/Slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload="Slider();">
    <Header:main runat="server" ID="header"></Header:main>
    <Leftpnl:left runat="server" ID="pnlLeft"></Leftpnl:left>
    <RightPnl:right runat="server" ID="pnlRight"></RightPnl:right>

    <div class="slider">
        <img id="slide_1" src="Images/Carousel/1.jpg" alt="" />
        <img id="slide_2" src="Images/Carousel/2.jpg" alt="" />
        <img id="slide_3" src="Images/Carousel/3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a possible conflict between "../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" from Pane_Right.ascx and "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" from Home.aspx. Always include only one copy of jquery javascript.

Comment: @Igor Thanks. Just noticed that.